# how are abs, sign etc implemented in F#

Tags: f#, inline

I found that:

```
abs -10
abs -10L
```

both work. So I wondered how F# implemented this and did a search in the source code:

```
    type AbsDynamicImplTable<'T>() = 
    let AbsDynamic x            = AbsDynamicImplTable<_>.Result x

    [<CompiledName("Abs")>]
    let inline abs (x: ^T) : ^T = 
         AbsDynamic x
         when ^T : ^T = absImpl x
```

And I am confused with these.

As I know in a function like `abs`, we must compare the input with 0, and there are different 0s for different types.

Thanks.

Comment: you don't have to compare X with 0 to find its absolute value - you can compare it with -X.

Comment: @Simon seems a good point. BUT, your method is not correct. Consider x=-2147483648.

Comment: yes, good point - though I suspect that you'd get the same exception trying to evaluate -X in that case as abs() ought to throw anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add some explanation to the code posted by ChaosPandion, the problem with F# functions like `abs` is that they can work with any numeric type. There is no way to express this just using F#/.NET generics - the only supported constrains are that type parameter implements a certain interface or has a constructor, but there is no constraint for numeric types.

So, F# also supports static constraints (the type parameter is `^a` instead of usual `'a`) and these are processed at compile time using inlining (this also explains why the function has to be `inline`). You can write you own function with static constraints by using built-in functions from `LanguagePrimitives` which contains many useful functions that require some constraints:

```
> let inline half (num: ^a) : ^a =
     LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt< (^a) > num 2
  ;;
val inline half : ^a -> ^a 
   when ^a : (static member DivideByInt : ^a * int -> ^a)

> half 42.0;;
val it : float = 21.0

> half 42.0f;;
val it : float32 = 21.0f
```

Note that constraints are inferred - `DivideByInt` requires that the type has `DivideByInt` member, so our function requires the same thing (and it will work with your own type if it has this member too, which is quite useful!).

In addition to this, the implementation of `abs` uses two additional tricks that are allowed only in the F# library - it specifies different code (to be used when inlining) for different types (using `when ^a:int = ....`) and a fallback case, which uses `Abs` member, so it will work with any explicitly listed type or a type with `Abs` member. Another trick is the `retype` function, which "changes the type", but doesn't contain any code - the only purpose is to make the code type-check, but this could be very unsafe - so this is used only in F# libraries.

Answer (score 8):

Actually that Abs table will call this:

```
let inline abs_impl (x: ^a) : ^a = 
     (^a: (static member Abs : ^a -> ^a) (x))
     when ^a : int32       = let x : int32     = retype x in if x >= 0 then x else -x
     when ^a : float       = let x : float     = retype x in if x >= 0.0 then x else -x
     when ^a : float32     = let x : float32   = retype x in if x >= 0.0f then x else -x
     when ^a : int64       = let x : int64     = retype x in if x >= 0L then x else -x
     when ^a : nativeint   = let x : nativeint = retype x in if x >= 0n then x else -x
     when ^a : int16       = let x : int16     = retype x in if x >= 0s then x else -x
     when ^a : sbyte       = let x : sbyte     = retype x in if x >= 0y then x else -x
     when ^a : decimal     = System.Math.Abs(retype x : decimal)
```

Comment: +1 for the actual implementation, but I guess the first version of my answer was correct.